# Django modelform will not save

Tags: python, django, django-forms, modelform

I have made a form which allows users to create a job listing, I have declared all the fields in my model and have created a model form and a view. Adding things to the model through the admin panel works fine and the form displays perfectly on the website. Pressing the submit button also throws no errors however it does not save the data. Any help appreciated, thanks!

Model -

```
class JobListing(models.Model):

    region_choice = (
        ('1', 'Auckland'),
        ('2', 'Wellington'),
        ('3', 'Christchurch')
    )
    industry_choice = (
        ('1', 'Accounting'),
        ('2', 'Agriculture, fishing & forestry'),
        ('3', 'Automotive'),
        ('4', 'Banking, finance & insurance'),
        ('5', 'Construction & Architecture'),
        ('6', 'Customer service'),
    )
    employment_type_choice = (
        ('1', 'Full Time'),
        ('2', 'Part Time'),
        ('3', 'One-off'),
        ('4', 'Other')
    )

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True)
    business_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    pay_rate = models.FloatField()
    employment_type = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=employment_type_choice)
    job_description = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    business_address_region = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=region_choice)
    business_address_suburb = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    business_industry = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=industry_choice)
    job_id = models.AutoField("ID", primary_key=True, editable=False, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Job Listing'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s" % self.business_name
```

Forms -

```
class JobListingForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = JobListing
        fields = ['business_name', 'pay_rate', 'employment_type', 'job_description', 'business_address_region',
            'business_address_suburb', 'business_industry']
        widgets = {
            'business_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-input', 'required': 'true', 'placeholder': 'Name of Business'}),
            'pay_rate': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-input', 'required': 'true', 'placeholder': 'Hourly Rate or One Off Amount'}),
            'employment_type': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-input', 'required': 'true'}),
            'job_description': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-textarea', 'required': 'true',
                'placeholder': 'Tell us additional information about your job listing e.g. Times, Business Info, Number of positions etc. (2000 Character Limit)'}),
            'business_address_region': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-input', 'required': 'true'}),
            'business_address_suburb': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-input', 'required': 'true', 'placeholder': 'Business Suburb'}),
            'business_industry': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-input', 'required': 'true'}),
        }
```

URLS -

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from profiles import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^createjoblisting/', views.createjoblisting, name='createjoblisting'),

)
```

Views -

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from forms import JobListingForm
from models import JobListing


def createjoblisting(request):

    f = JobListingForm(request.POST)

    if f.is_valid():
        profile = f.save(commit=False)
        profile.user = request.user
        profile.save()

    context = {
        "form": f
    }

    return render(request, "createjoblisting.html", context)
```

createjoblisting.html -

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<div id="createjoblisting">
    <h1 class="pageheader">Create a Job Listing</h1>
    <form class="createjoblisting" id="createjoblisting_form" method="post" action="{% url 'createjoblisting' %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.non_field_errors }}
        <p> <label for="id_username" class="form-input-label">Business Name</label><br>
        {{ form.business_name }}<br><p>
        <p><label for="id_username" class="form-input-label">Pay Rate</label><br>
        {{ form.pay_rate }}<br></p>
        <p><label for="id_username" class="form-input-label">Employment Type</label><br>
        {{ form.employment_type }}<br><p>
        <p><label for="id_username" class="form-input-label">Job Description</label><br>
        {{ form.job_description }}<br><p>
        <p><label for="id_username" class="form-input-label">Business Region</label><br>
        {{ form.business_address_region }}<br><p>
        <p><label for="id_username" class="form-input-label">Business Suburb</label><br>
        {{ form.business_address_suburb }}<br><p>
        <p><label for="id_username" class="form-input-label">Business Industry</label><br>
        {{ form.business_industry }}<br><p>
        <button type="submit" class="form-button">Create Job Listing</button>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Any error or traceback?

Comment: nope, this is the only thing that happens when I submit http://puu.sh/j4szb/1c815c6e75.png

Comment: How can the form be saved before checking it is valid

Comment: Just removed that part, it was just for testing but it doesnt work even with the is_valid code below.

Comment: I suspect one of the form fields is not valid. What happens when you just render {{form}} in your template? (you render the non_field errors, but not the field errors)

Comment: I guess your form is not valid, try to add an else statement and add following code in the else statement :
import pdb
pdb.set_trace()

This will "pause" the execution of your code letting you know what's happening, for example you could display the f.errors in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not displaying any of the field errors in your template. For each of `{{ form.field }}`, you also need to have `{{ form.field.errors }}`.

```
<p> <label for="id_username" class="form-input-label">Business Name</label><br>
    {{ form.business_name }}
    {{ form.business_name.errors }}
<br><p>
```

That will allow you to see the reason that the form is invalid.